# iFrame permalinks on Wordpress

Tags: permalinks

Can someone help me fix this links from https://smallcaps.com.au/stocks/?symbol=DTR  make it https://smallcaps.com.au/stocks/DTR ? the link I posted here is handle by iFrame, I just want to make the links looks clean instead of having "?symbol="

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible.

The iframe on your page is generated by a script from WebLink that requires the `?symbol=` parameter in the URL to be able to generate the correct iframe.

If you rewrote the URL the way you want the script would not work, since the `symbol` parameter doesn't exist anymore. WordPress would be able to access the value, but the script would not see it anymore, and it's the script that creates the iframe.

You will need to check with WebLink to see if it's possible to set the stock symbol for the iframe a different way.

Comment: but my colleague told me that there is an option to add codes in htaccess but i havent tried it yet. not sure if will worked. this is why i am hoping someone can give me answers.

Comment: That won’t work. I’ve explained why in my answer. You can change the URL, but the iframe won’t work anymore.

Comment: okay Jacob thanks for your response it is highly appreciated.